# Household import error

Tags: civimember, error

I'm unable to upload my household members into a new civiCRM install. My data is set out under these headings:
House ID, Household Name, Household email, member ID, member First Name, member Last Name, member Email, Mobile Phone, Address Line 1, Address Line 2, City, State, Postal Code, Date Admitted, Date Paid up to, member2 First Name, member2 Last Name, member2 Email,  member2 ID

I have matched the headings ensuring all red* fields are covered.

Everything is fine in preview (step 3 of import) but after 'import now' in step 4 I receive this error:  Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: household_name

I have definitely matched the household_name in line 2 of my data... Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What release of CiviCRM are you using?  It's always helpful to know this, plus what CMS you are using (Drupal, WP, BackDrop)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I believe I'm using V5.41.2 and I'm using WP.

Answer (score 2):

Some rows in your csv you using to import might have missing household name.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have ensures all fields have data and still receive the same error.